Rigid Body Transformations - Robotics
In a robotics application I have a calibration grid with reference features at known positions from its center and I used that grid to teach a frame to a robot. This frame represents the position of that grid to the robot, which is the global reference. I know that this frame is not totally accurate, especially in Rx and Ry. Using a camera and a micrometre I was able to collect the 3D position data (XYZ) of all the features in my calibration grid. So this dataset represents the error in positioning from my frame to my calibration grid.
To find the Rotation Matrix that represents my data I used my dataset to create a covariance matrix and then use Singular Value Decomposition, SVD, to break it down into the 3 matrices (U, S and V.T). So by doing U.T @ (V.T)T, I calculated the rotation matrix that represents the position of my calibration grid in reference to my taught frame. Let's call it Rmeas.
The next step would be multiplying the rotation matrix from my frame (Rframe), which is in reference to my global reference, with Rmeas and then extracting the Euler angle from this final rotation matrix. Here is my problem:
When I extracted the angles from Rframe@Rmeas I noticed that my Rz was in the opposite direction! In that particular case, the Rz from Rmeas was subtracting from Rframe while it should be adding, so naturally when I checked the results by moving the robot in X and Y axis I noticed that it was drifting way even more than before. To get the Rz in the right direction I had to multiply my Rframe with the Transpose of Rmeas (Rframe @ Rmeas.T). Which to me seems unintuitive, because by multiplying by the Transpose of Rmeas I am actually undoing the rotation. Could someone please explain it to me why should I use the Transpose?
Thank you very much for helping out.

Without understanding everything you did: The aim was to undo the error, not to double it. So if $P_{actual}=QP_{exact}$, then also $P_{exact}=Q^TP_{actual}$

Thanks for your comment @LutzLehmann! To my understanding, when I do Rframe * Rmeas I am getting the orientation of my measurements in the global reference frame, isn't it? At least that is what I do when I have a position in the User Frame and I want to get the coordinates of that position in the Global Reference Frame. I taught that would be the same principle.

The problem was caused when I calculated the rotation matrix for my real-life measurements, after doing the SVD. The correct formula is R=U@Vt
I was transposing U and Vt to calculate R, that resulted in an inverted rotation matrix that required me to transpose it every time I wanted to calculate something with it. Now everything makes sense!
